# JavaScript onScroll not working in Google Apps Script web app

Tags: javascript, scroll, google-apps-script, google-sites, google-caja

I have created a table in HTML and added the styles using CSS and added a scrolling element through javascript. i attached the sample source code with this post. The scrolling is not working when i place the code in google site. Please help me resolve this problem. I got the sample code from the below site link.

http://blog.oxagile.com/2009/10/26/scrollable-html-table-with-fixed-header-for-ie-7-ie-8-firefox-35-chrome/

Coding in HTML file named "table.html" is below

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table#table-body, table#table-header, table#table-footer
      {
        border-spacing:0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border:1px solid;
        table-layout:fixed;
        width:1000px;
        border:1px solid #000;
      }

      table#table-header th
      {
        background:#c2a1a1;
      }

      table#table-footer td
      {
        background:#a39393;
      }

      table#table-body td
      {
        background:#e1d9d9;
      }

      table#table-body td, table#table-header th, table#table-footer td
      {
        border:1px solid #000;
        width:100px;
        height:30px;
        overflow:hidden;
        white-space:nowrap; 
      }

      div#header-container, div#footer-container
      {
        overflow:hidden;
      }

      div#scroll
      {
        width:500px;
        overflow:hidden;
        max-height:150px;
        padding-left:1px;
      }

      div#fake-scroll-container
      {
        width:500px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
      }

      div#y-fake-scroll
      {
        overflow-y:scroll; 
        overflow-x:hidden;
        background:transparent; 
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        position:absolute;
        max-height:149px;
        top:31px;
      }

      div#x-fake-scroll
      {
        height:40px;
        margin-top:-23px;
        overflow-x:auto;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        margin-top:expression('0px');/* IE 7 fix*/
        height:expression('17px'); /* IE 7 fix*/
      }

      div#y-scroll
      {
        max-height:150px;
        overflow-y:auto;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow:scroll;
        width:1010px;
        padding:0px 1px 1px 1px;
      }

      div#header-container
      {
        padding:1px 1px 0 1px;
      }

      div#footer-container
      {
        padding:0 1px;
      }      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fake-scroll-container">

      <div id="header-container">
        <table id="table-header" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
            <th>Column 5</th>
            <th>Column 6</th>
            <th>Column 7</th>
            <th>Column 8</th>
            <th>Column 9</th>
            <th>Column 10</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div id="scroll">
        <table id="table-body" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Cell 1.1</td>
            <td>Cell 1.2</td>
            <td>Cell 1.3</td>
            <td>Cell 1.4</td>
            <td>Cell 1.5</td>
            <td>Cell 1.6</td>
            <td>Cell 1.7</td>
            <td>Cell 1.8</td>
            <td>Cell 1.9</td>
            <td>Cell 1.10</td>      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell 2.1</td>
            <td>Cell 2.2</td>
            <td>Cell 2.3</td>
            <td>Cell 2.4</td>
            <td>Cell 2.5</td>
            <td>Cell 2.6</td>
            <td>Cell 2.7</td>
            <td>Cell 2.8</td>
            <td>Cell 2.9</td>
            <td>Cell 2.10</td>      
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td>Cell 3.1</td>
            <td>Cell 3.2</td>
            <td>Cell 3.3</td>
            <td>Cell 3.4</td>
            <td>Cell 3.5</td>
            <td>Cell 3.6</td>
            <td>Cell 3.7</td>
            <td>Cell 3.8</td>
            <td>Cell 3.9</td>
            <td>Cell 3.10</td>      
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td>Cell 4.1</td>
            <td>Cell 4.2</td>
            <td>Cell 4.3</td>
            <td>Cell 4.4</td>
            <td>Cell 4.5</td>
            <td>Cell 4.6</td>
            <td>Cell 4.7</td>
            <td>Cell 4.8</td>
            <td>Cell 4.9</td>
            <td>Cell 4.10</td>      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell 5.1</td>
            <td>Cell 5.2</td>
            <td>Cell 5.3</td>
            <td>Cell 5.4</td>
            <td>Cell 5.5</td>
            <td>Cell 5.6</td>
            <td>Cell 5.7</td>
            <td>Cell 5.8</td>
            <td>Cell 5.9</td>
            <td>Cell 5.10</td>      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell 6.1</td>
            <td>Cell 6.2</td>
            <td>Cell 6.3</td>
            <td>Cell 6.4</td>
            <td>Cell 6.5</td>
            <td>Cell 6.6</td>
            <td>Cell 6.7</td>
            <td>Cell 6.8</td>
            <td>Cell 6.9</td>
            <td>Cell 6.10</td>      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell 7.1</td>
            <td>Cell 7.2</td>
            <td>Cell 7.3</td>
            <td>Cell 7.4</td>
            <td>Cell 7.5</td>
            <td>Cell 7.6</td>
            <td>Cell 7.7</td>
            <td>Cell 7.8</td>
            <td>Cell 7.9</td>
            <td>Cell 7.10</td>      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell 8.1</td>
            <td>Cell 8.2</td>
            <td>Cell 8.3</td>
            <td>Cell 8.4</td>
            <td>Cell 8.5</td>
            <td>Cell 8.6</td>
            <td>Cell 8.7</td>
            <td>Cell 8.8</td>
            <td>Cell 8.9</td>
            <td>Cell 8.10</td>      
          </tr>
        </table>    
      </div>
      <div id="y-fake-scroll">
        <div id="y-table-emulator" style="width:40px;">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="x-fake-scroll">
        <div id="x-table-emulator">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>
        var YtableEmulator = document.getElementById('y-table-emulator');
        var XtableEmulator = document.getElementById('x-table-emulator');
        var table = document.getElementById('table-body');

        YtableEmulator.style.height = table.clientHeight == 0 ? "330px" : table.clientHeight + "px";
        XtableEmulator.style.width = table.clientWidth + "px";

        var scrollablePanel = document.getElementById('scroll');
        var headerContainer = document.getElementById('header-container');
        var footerContainer = document.getElementById('footer-container');
        var YfakeScrollablePanel = document.getElementById('y-fake-scroll');
        var XfakeScrollablePanel = document.getElementById('x-fake-scroll');


        YfakeScrollablePanel.style.top = headerContainer.clientHeight == 0 ? "34px" : headerContainer.clientHeight + "px";
        scrollablePanel.onscroll = function (e) {
          XfakeScrollablePanel.scrollTop = scrollablePanel.scrollTop;
        }
          YfakeScrollablePanel.onscroll = function (e) {
            scrollablePanel.scrollTop = YfakeScrollablePanel.scrollTop;
          }
            XfakeScrollablePanel.onscroll = function (e) {
              scrollablePanel.scrollLeft = XfakeScrollablePanel.scrollLeft;
              headerContainer.scrollLeft = XfakeScrollablePanel.scrollLeft;
              footerContainer.scrollLeft = XfakeScrollablePanel.scrollLeft;
            }
              alert('but this is fine!');
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Coding in the GAS file named "Code.gs" is here

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('table').evaluate();
}
```

I think the .onscroll inside the script tag is not working while publishing the project.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks & Regards,
chockalingam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated in the issue tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1781, but I want to post on SO too, for completeness.

This seems to be an issue with Caja. I pasted your HTML code into Caja Playground (http://caja.appspot.com) and see the same behavior - moving the scrollbars has no effect.
Please raise this on the Google Caja issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/list

Comment: Special thanks to Mr. Jan Kleinert for guide me to post the issue in Google Caja issue tracker forum. Thanks a lot @Jan Kleinert

Answer (score 1):

I raised this issue in Google Caja issue tracker and they fixed it. You can review it [**here.**](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1512)

Actually I want to use the scrolling with the table header as fixed in the Google site.

Google Caja team raised the modification to Apps Script team, you can review it [**here.**](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/detail?r=5029)

This issue is yet to deploy for Apps Script. Please follow the above issue link for the further updates regarding this issue.

Please support to deploy this in Apps Script as soon as possible.

Comment: This concept is deployed successfully tnx for who r all supported to fix this issue. Tnx a ton to all.